# web server in ruby and connection keep-alive

Tags: ruby, web-services, sockets, http, io

Web server example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'socket'
require 'thread'

class WebServer
  LINE_TERMINATOR = "\r\n".freeze

  def initialize(host, port)
    @server = TCPServer.new(host, port)
  end

  def run
    response_body = 'Hello World!'.freeze
    response_headers = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK#{LINE_TERMINATOR}Connection: Keep-Alive#{LINE_TERMINATOR}Content-Length: #{response_body.bytesize}#{LINE_TERMINATOR}".freeze

    loop do
      Thread.new(@server.accept) do |socket|
        puts "request #{socket}"
        sleep 3
        socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, 1)
        socket.write(response_headers)
        socket.write(LINE_TERMINATOR)
        socket.write(response_body)
        # socket.close # if this line is uncommented then it's work.
      end
    end
  end
end

WebServer.new('localhost', 8888).run
```

if update browser without waiting for the end of the cycle then the following queries are not processed

How can handle incomming request which are persistent socket ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Keep around the sockets you get from the `@server.accept` call.  Store them in an array (`socket_array`).
2. Use the `IO.select` call on the array of sockets to get the set of sockets that can be read:

   ```
   ready = IO.select(socket_array)
   readable = ready[0]

   readable.each do |socket|
       # Read from socket here
       # Do the rest of processing here
   ```
3. Don't close the socket after you have sent the data.

If you need more details leave a comment - I can write more of the code.